# Eclipse Tricks and Tips plugin Extension Point

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I need to add an entry to a menu section in the Tips and Tricks help dialog in eclipse. For that I am searching which Extension Point from Eclipse to use.
I am using eclipse 2019-06 and if I consult the documentation, I see no extension point for this help entry:

[image]

Eclipse 2019 Plugin documentation is [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_help_contexts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't done using that extension point.

The `about.ini` file in the 'feature plug-in' for an installed feature can contain a `tipsAndTricksHref` property which gives the help topic href to use. For example the JDT about.ini contains:

```
tipsAndTricksHref=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html
```

So you must create a feature. You then create a 'feature plugin' - which is a plugin with the same id as the feature. The about.ini goes in the plugin. The feature.xml must list the 'feature plugin' and your other plugins. You must use a feature based build for the RCP build.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However I still have an issue with the fact that if I add the about.ini file in a 'feature plugin', I don't see the entry Tips and Tricks to my plugin, there is something else I need to do?

Comment: Is it actually a feature plugin? You must be using features and the plugin id must be the same as the feature id.

Comment: It is a plugin, but if I add the about.ini file in the plugin it doesn't work, so I have created a feature plugin and put the about.ini there, but it didn't work either.

Comment: No, you have to have a feature, and then you have to have a plug-in with the same id as the feature. The about.ini goes in the plugin. The feature.xml must list that plugin and your other plugins. You have to build your RCP as a feature based RCP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. What I am trying now is to make tipsAndTricksHref indicate towards a xml table of contents but your solution worked with html.

Comment: The tips and tricks dialog ends up calling `IWorkbenchHelpSystem.displayHelpResource` - I don't think that supports a table of contents.